Autoplay in blueprint in unreal engine 5.4
I am using unreal engine for cenamatic videos.
I have two Meshes one static n another skeletal mesh. I crated one animation for each using blender. Both working at level perfectly.
Recently i am trying blueprint class in UE 5.4.
I need help to create a blueprint for both. Which automatically play with animated asset while drag it into level. Pls help me How to create animatable blue print for both.
I just tried blueprint assigning mesh n it's animation, but it's animation only play while simulation button on...
